# Notification bar changes page layout

Tags: feature-request, notifications, notification-bar

When there is engineering work being carried out (like now), a notice appears near the top of StackExchange sites reading:

"There may be network connectivity issues today as we upgrade networking equipment."

This line shuffles everything else downwards, and if you're working near the top of a StackExchange site and happen to be very familiar with the layout, you have to readjust your reflexes and instincts for the day. It's very off-putting!

Can this notification be moved to someplace that doesn't affect the placement of other elements?

Comment: What are you clicking that's at a fixed location below the system message? All the fixed position stuff (nav bar, logo, buttons) are above the message. Just below the message the question starts, and questions have a variable height anyway

Comment: @Michael: Question title. Question voting. Question favourite. Tags on the RHS. I think the rest of the problem remains despite the variable height of the question text due to the mental confusion that the layout has changed so slightly. A psychologist could tell you more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can this notification be moved to someplace that doesn't affect the placement of other elements?

There not being much white space on the SE site layouts, the only option would be right above the footer, where no one would see it, which would defeat its purpose. Besides, it's not even an inch tall—is it really that annoying?

Comment: The problem isn't that it's large and intrusive: it's neither. The problem is that everything else gets moved an inch down and, yes, that's enough to ruin the UI experience when you have learned behaviour from lots of time spent on SO.

Comment: @Tomalak Ok, but where would be a better place to put it?

Comment: if I knew, I'd have a concrete suggestion. Instead, I'd like to open the floor to ideas.